# Retrieve value from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a multidim array that I can view using **print_r($users)**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => crustacea
            [created_on] => 2010-08-07 19:54:32
            [active] => 1
        )
)
```

I can also use **print_r($users[0])**.  Since there's only one member in $users, the output looks somewhat the same.

I can't see how to retrieve the value *crustacea*.  **echo $users[0]['username'];** doesn't do it.  Examples I can find are **echo $users['name_of_array']['username'];**  -- but I don't have a name of array to work with.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$user[0] is not an array but an object as indicated by `[0] => stdClass Object`.

```
echo $users[0]->username;
```

Answer (score 1):

$user[0] is object and not an array. You can access your value by doing

```
$users[0]->username;
```

Or you could cast/convert your object into an array like

```
((array)$users[0])['username'];
```

Comment: I am accepting the other answer merely because it came in earlier.  I appreciate the extra tip on casting as array.  Thanks very much.